# Asana Batch tasks creation

Tags: heroku, asana

I am getting 500 HTTP error on some random requests when 8 threads creates tasks.

Error messages are funny:

```
25 tan reindeer cheer equally
10 sad sharks rush well
```

Please let me know what is the best way for fast (parallel) task creation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us examples of tasks where it failed? It could be related to follower/assignee, esp. by email.